# Duplicate JLabels in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am making UNO game in JAVA. I am having problems with duplicate labels. I have a JFrame. In it, there are 7 JPanels. Every JPanel has a JLabel inside it. The JLabels are stored in an arrayList in another class. Every JLabel has an image inside it. The arrayList has duplicate JLabels inside it. I am getting the JLabels into the JPanels randomly. But when a duplicate JLabel is called, it is skipped. Help please.

The Deck:

```
public class Deck {
  private ArrayList<JLabel> cards;

Zero zero = new Zero();
One one = new One();
Two two = new Two();
Three three = new Three();
Four four = new Four();
Five five = new Five();
Six six = new Six();
Seven seven = new Seven();
Eight eight = new Eight();
Nine nine = new Nine();
Reverse reverse = new Reverse();
Skip skip = new Skip();
DrawTwo drawTwo = new DrawTwo();
Wild wild = new Wild();
WildDrawFour wildDrawFour = new WildDrawFour();

public Deck() {
    cards = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    cards.add(zero.getLabelR());
    cards.add(zero.getLabelY());
    cards.add(zero.getLabelG());
    cards.add(zero.getLabelB());
    cards.add(one.getLabelR());
    cards.add(one.getLabelR());
    cards.add(one.getLabelB());
    cards.add(one.getLabelG());
    cards.add(one.getLabelY());
    cards.add(one.getLabelB());
    cards.add(one.getLabelG());
    cards.add(one.getLabelY());
    cards.add(two.getLabelB());
    cards.add(two.getLabelG());
    cards.add(two.getLabelY());
    cards.add(two.getLabelR());
    cards.add(two.getLabelB());
    cards.add(two.getLabelG());
    cards.add(two.getLabelY());
    cards.add(two.getLabelR());
    cards.add(three.getLabelB());
    cards.add(three.getLabelG());
    cards.add(three.getLabelY());
    cards.add(three.getLabelR());
    cards.add(three.getLabelB());
    cards.add(three.getLabelG());
    cards.add(three.getLabelY());
    cards.add(three.getLabelR());
    cards.add(four.getLabelB());
    cards.add(four.getLabelG());
    cards.add(four.getLabelY());
    cards.add(four.getLabelR());
    cards.add(four.getLabelB());
    cards.add(four.getLabelG());
    cards.add(four.getLabelY());
    cards.add(four.getLabelR());
    cards.add(five.getLabelB());
    cards.add(five.getLabelG());
    cards.add(five.getLabelY());
    cards.add(five.getLabelR());
    cards.add(five.getLabelB());
    cards.add(five.getLabelG());
    cards.add(five.getLabelY());
    cards.add(five.getLabelR());
    cards.add(six.getLabelB());
    cards.add(six.getLabelG());
    cards.add(six.getLabelY());
    cards.add(six.getLabelR());
    cards.add(six.getLabelB());
    cards.add(six.getLabelG());
    cards.add(six.getLabelY());
    cards.add(six.getLabelR());
    cards.add(seven.getLabelB());
    cards.add(seven.getLabelG());
    cards.add(seven.getLabelY());
    cards.add(seven.getLabelR());
    cards.add(seven.getLabelB());
    cards.add(seven.getLabelG());
    cards.add(seven.getLabelY());
    cards.add(seven.getLabelR());
    cards.add(eight.getLabelB());
    cards.add(eight.getLabelG());
    cards.add(eight.getLabelY());
    cards.add(eight.getLabelR());
    cards.add(eight.getLabelB());
    cards.add(eight.getLabelG());
    cards.add(eight.getLabelY());
    cards.add(eight.getLabelR());
    cards.add(nine.getLabelB());
    cards.add(nine.getLabelG());
    cards.add(nine.getLabelY());
    cards.add(nine.getLabelR());
    cards.add(nine.getLabelB());
    cards.add(nine.getLabelG());
    cards.add(nine.getLabelY());
    cards.add(nine.getLabelR());
    cards.add(reverse.getLabelB());
    cards.add(reverse.getLabelG());
    cards.add(reverse.getLabelY());
    cards.add(reverse.getLabelR());
    cards.add(reverse.getLabelB());
    cards.add(reverse.getLabelG());
    cards.add(reverse.getLabelY());
    cards.add(reverse.getLabelR());
    cards.add(skip.getLabelB());
    cards.add(skip.getLabelG());
    cards.add(skip.getLabelY());
    cards.add(skip.getLabelR());
    cards.add(skip.getLabelB());
    cards.add(skip.getLabelG());
    cards.add(skip.getLabelY());
    cards.add(skip.getLabelR());
    cards.add(drawTwo.getLabelB());
    cards.add(drawTwo.getLabelG());
    cards.add(drawTwo.getLabelY());
    cards.add(drawTwo.getLabelR());
    cards.add(drawTwo.getLabelB());
    cards.add(drawTwo.getLabelG());
    cards.add(drawTwo.getLabelY());
    cards.add(drawTwo.getLabelR());
    cards.add(wild.getLabel());
    cards.add(wild.getLabel());
    cards.add(wild.getLabel());
    cards.add(wild.getLabel());
    cards.add(wildDrawFour.getLabel());
    cards.add(wildDrawFour.getLabel());
    cards.add(wildDrawFour.getLabel());
    cards.add(wildDrawFour.getLabel());

    shuffle();

}

public ArrayList<JLabel> getCards() {
    return cards;
}

public void shuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
}
```

}

The GUI:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    JPanel card1;
    JPanel card2;
    JPanel card3;
    JPanel card4;
    JPanel card5;
    JPanel card6;``
    JPanel card7;

    Back back = new Back();
    Zero zero = new Zero();
    One one = new One();
    Two two = new Two();
    Three three = new Three();
    Four four = new Four();
    Five five = new Five();
    Six six = new Six();
    Seven seven = new Seven();
    Eight eight = new Eight();
    Nine nine = new Nine();
    Reverse reverse = new Reverse();
    Skip skip = new Skip();
    DrawTwo drawTwo = new DrawTwo();
    Wild wild = new Wild();
    WildDrawFour wildDrawFour = new WildDrawFour();

    Deck ar = new Deck();
    Random r = new Random();

    public GUI() {
        super("UNO");
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(1150, 690);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(35, 176, 40));

        int a = r.nextInt(100) + r.nextInt(9) + 1;
        card1 = new JPanel();
        card1.setLayout(null);
        card1.setBounds(65, 500, 85, 120);
        card1.setBackground(new Color(35, 176, 40));
        card1.add(ar.getCards().get(a)).setBounds(0, 0, 85, 120);
        System.out.println(ar.getCards().get(a));
        System.out.println(a);

        int b = 0;
        while (true) {
            b = r.nextInt(100) + r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            if (b != a) {
                card2 = new JPanel();
                card2.setLayout(null);
                card2.setBounds(215, 500, 85, 120);
                card2.setBackground(new Color(35, 176, 40));
                card2.add(ar.getCards().get(b)).setBounds(0, 0, 85, 120);
                System.out.println(ar.getCards().get(b));
                System.out.println(b);
                break;
            } else
                continue;
        }

        int c = 0;
        while (true) {
            c = r.nextInt(100) + r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            if (c != a && c != b) {
                card3 = new JPanel();
                card3.setLayout(null);
                card3.setBounds(365, 500, 85, 120);
                card3.setBackground(new Color(35, 176, 40));
                card3.add(ar.getCards().get(c)).setBounds(0, 0, 85, 120);
                System.out.println(ar.getCards().get(c));
                System.out.println(c);
                break;
            } else
                continue;
        }

        int d = 0;
        while (true) {
            d = r.nextInt(100) + r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            if (d != a && d != b && d != c) {
                card4 = new JPanel();
                card4.setLayout(null);
                card4.setBounds(515, 500, 85, 120);
                card4.setBackground(new Color(35, 176, 40));
                card4.add(ar.getCards().get(d)).setBounds(0, 0, 85, 120);
                ;
                System.out.println(ar.getCards().get(d));
                System.out.println(d);
                break;
            } else
                continue;
        }

        int e = 0;
        while (true) {
            e = r.nextInt(100) + r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            if (e != a && e != b && e != c && e != b) {
                card5 = new JPanel();
                card5.setLayout(null);
                card5.setBounds(665, 500, 85, 120);
                card5.setBackground(new Color(35, 176, 40));
                card5.add(ar.getCards().get(e)).setBounds(0, 0, 85, 120);
                System.out.println(ar.getCards().get(e));
                System.out.println(e);
                break;
            } else
                continue;
        }

        int f = 0;
        while (true) {
            f = r.nextInt(100) + r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            if (f != a && f != b && f != c && f != d && f != e) {
                card6 = new JPanel();
                card6.setLayout(null);
                card6.setBounds(815, 500, 85, 120);
                card6.setBackground(new Color(35, 176, 40));
                card6.add(ar.getCards().get(f)).setBounds(0, 0, 85, 120);
                System.out.println(ar.getCards().get(f));
                System.out.println(f);
                break;
            } else
                continue;
        }

        card7 = new JPanel();
        card7.setLayout(null);
        card7.setBounds(965, 500, 85, 120);
        card7.setBackground(new Color(35, 176, 40));
        card7.add(back.getLabel()).setBounds(0, 0, 85, 120);

        add(card1);
        add(card2);
        add(card3);
        add(card4);
        add(card5);
        add(card6);
        add(card7);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
        g2.drawRoundRect(965, 523, 100, 135, 15, 15);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2.drawLine(0, 480, 1150, 480);
    }

}
```

When duplication doesn't occur:

[image]

When duplication occurs:

[image]

Comment: All `Components` can only have 1 parent. You need to make duplicate JLabels

Comment: Note the Icon can be shared, but your must create a separate label for each panel.

Answer (score 1):

Swing components can't be shared by multiple parents.

However an `Icon` can be shared.

So your `get()` method needs to be changed to get a random `Icon`, not a random label. Then once you retrieve the `Icon`, you create a new `JLabel` and add the `Icon` to the label. Then you add the label to the form.